# PayPal preapproval, verify payment before executing

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

In my application I ask a user for preapproval and I create and execute a payment using this preapproval key afterwards.
Is there any way to know if the preapproved payment can be executed before executing the payment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is not. This is similar to providing a free trial to a consumer. You may have their agreement to be billed on certain dates but it's not guaranteed their funding sources can be charged. Below are a couple options you may be able to use to increase approval rates.

Typically I see merchants who've received high decline rates start to offer an immediate first payment under $1.00 which validates the funding source. This has greatly increased their approval rates but keep in mind this is not a guarantee for payment in the future.

Outside of this, the only other option is to perform a GetVerifiedStatus API call (approval for use required) which advises if the PayPal account has completed the steps to achieve PayPal verification. If a verified response is received you know they've added a funding source to their PayPal account. Again however this doesn't guarantee the funding source will be approved when attempted.